# How to unlock Boot-loader of android Phone?

Tags: dual-boot, android, bootloader, ubuntu-for-android

i Want to unlock boot-loader of android phone. Actually i want to dual boot the android phone with android and Ubuntu .

For that i have to unlock boot-loader first . Whenever i run fast boot oem unlock then it display:

waiting for devices ..... nothing more then.

Any suggestion or link for unlock android boot-loader. i have Mediatek chip set enable android phone (i.e Chinese android phone).

Comment: you should ask android

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built-in the Ubuntu Touch OS, you should simply install it on your device and set it to dual boot using the System Settings.

But first make sure your device is officially supported otherwise you might be getting yourself into an intense adventure.

Comment: Hi Yaron ,first i have to unlock bootloader.

Comment: What is your cellular phone model?

Comment: i have Micromax Tab. MD708 , CPU MTK8317(mediaTek). fyi Lenovo A1000 have also same chipset.

Comment: There's no official way supplied by Canonical but you should certainly try helping by creating a port yourself (It can be very complicated: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting).

You may want to try and look for rooting tutorials on Google first, good luck!

Comment: ya i have google it but i always stuck at unlocking bootloader point..if any guide for unlocking bootloader.

Comment: I have general knowledge of the process and some experience with it but I'm not familiar with this device and as far as I'm concerned this process is device specific.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12952/discussion-between-yaron-and-i-max-77)

Comment: sorry for delay Yaron ..
exact name of the device is micromax canvas tab P650 having chipset MTK8389.